# Instantiate and Destroy Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to instantiate and destroy a prefab on the run. I tried these:

```
public Transform prefab;     //I attached a prefab in Unity Editor

Object o = Instantiate(prefab);
//using this I cannot get the transform component (I don't know why) so useless

Transform o=(Transform)Instantiate(prefab);
//gives transform and transform component cannot be destroyed

GameObject o=(GameObject)Instantiate(prefab);
//invalid cast
```

So how to do that?

Comment: You need to study some OO concept. It's all about variable TYPE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to declare your Instance as Object, if you do you get the ancestor object which it has not the transform component.

```
public GameObject prefab;
GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab);
```

If you want get transform component just type `obj.transform`.
If you want destroy the object type `Destroy(obj);`.

Comment: cannot convert implicitly...so I added (GameObject) there and it ran successfully but I need to check a few more things to verify and then implement it

Answer (score 3):

> gives transform and transform component cannot be destroyed

Destroy the `GameObject` to which the `Transform` component is attached to:

```
GameObject.Destroy(o.gameObject);
```

`Instantiate` method returns the same type of the object passed as parameter. Since it's a `Transform` you can't cast it to `GameObject`. Try this:

```
GameObject o=((Transform)Instantiate(prefab)).gameObject;
```

Comment: it says cannot cast from source to destination

Comment: Which part?  Both of Heisenbug's snippets work just fine, copied verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

Your codes does not make sense..

```
public Transform prefab;
Object o = Instantiate(prefab);
```

You are instantiating a Transform? Why dont you try attaching the prefab instead?

You should try:

```
public GameObject prefab; // attach the prefab in Unity Editor
GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab);
GameObject.Destroy(obj);
```

Comment: His code makes perfect sense.  The [official documents](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) even use the same `public Transform Prefab` notation.

Comment: `public Transform prefab;` is ok, you could declare the variable type as Transform or GameObject, depend on your demand.

Comment: This has bothered me for years, it seems it finally makes sense. "The Parent object will be copied" if a component. Basically if you want to only focus on the transform, copy it. Finally makes sense. I recommend looking up assigning game objects to scripts, unity answers has a nice explanation there on that.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the accepted answer is actually wrong.

When using the Instantiate function of the **[MonoBehaviour](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)** class we must specify the type of what we are instantiating. I highly recommend reading **[Instantiate API reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)**.

---

To instantiate a prefab as a **[GameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.html)**

```
GameObject g = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
```

To instantiate a prefab as a **[Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.html)** and provide a position in 3D space.

```
Transform t = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(1,10,11), new Quaternion(1,10,11,100));
```

To Destroy a component, which means you can destroy scripts attached to gameObjects as well as rigibodies and other components.

```
Destroy(g);
```

or

```
Destroy(t.gameObject)
```

---